# Avoiding redirection

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm trying to parse a site(written in ASP) and the crawler gets redirected to the main site. But what I'd like to do is to parse the given url, not the redirected one. Is there a way to do this?. I tried adding "REDIRECT=False" to the settings.py file without success.

Here's some output from the crawler:

```
2011-09-24 20:01:11-0300 [coto] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.cotodigital.com.ar/default.asp> from <GET http://www.cotodigital.com.ar/l.asp?cat=500&id=500>
2011-09-24 20:01:11-0300 [coto] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.cotodigital.com.ar/default.asp> from <GET http://www.cotodigital.com.ar/l.asp?cat=1513&id=1513>
2011-09-24 20:01:11-0300 [coto] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.cotodigital.com.ar/default.asp> from <GET http://www.cotodigital.com.ar/l.asp?cat=476&id=476>
2011-09-24 20:01:11-0300 [coto] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.cotodigital.com.ar/default.asp> from <GET http://www.cotodigital.com.ar/l.asp?cat=472&id=472>
2011-09-24 20:01:11-0300 [coto] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.cotodigital.com.ar/default.asp> from <GET http://www.cotodigital.com.ar/l.asp?cat=457&id=457>
2011-09-24 20:01:11-0300 [coto] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET http://www.cotodigital.com.ar/default.asp> from <GET http://www.cotodigital.com.ar/l.asp?cat=1097&id=1097>
```

Comment: How exactly are you retrieving the URL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`http://www.cotodigital.com.ar/l.asp?cat=1097&id=1097` redirects to `http://www.cotodigital.com.ar/default.asp` because HTTP response said to so. This happens because asp code is checking for some condition - a wrong page, or cookies, or user-agent, or referrer. Check the mentioned conditions.

UPDATE:
Just checked in my browser: the browser is also redirected to the main page, where i click 'Skip ads'. After that it works OK.

This means it sets some cookies, without which it redirects to the main page.

See also [Scrapy - how to manage cookies/sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981440/scrapy-how-to-manage-cookies-sessions)

Answer (score 1):

The original URL has nothing to scrape.  It returned 302, meaning there is no body, and the Location header indicates where to redirect to.  You need to figure out how to access the URL without being redirected, perhaps by authenticating.