# Scrapy doesn't follow 302 redirect

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Why scrapy doesn't follow 302 redirect? All I see in my logs is:

```
2015-01-22 20:37:18+0300 [spider] DEBUG: Redirecting (302) to <GET https://somesite.com/somepath1> from <POST https://somesite.com/somepath2>
```

Comment: Related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22795416/how-to-handle-302-redirect-in-scrapy and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7542829/avoiding-redirection.