# Webrawling in Python with Scrapy - How to force page to show breadcrumb menu?

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am building some Web Crawlers in Python with the Scrapy library. The goal is to get some data from a couple of shops.

When crawling, there are two kinds of sites:

1. Catalogue sites, which display products and link to..
2. Product sites, the sites where the different products of the shop can be viewed

Now, as a user, when I open a product site from a catalogue site, I am shown a "breadcrumb-style" menu - this shows me where I am. For example, if the shop would be an electronics shop and the product would be an iPhone, the breadcrumbs could show:

"Electronics -> Phones -> iPhones -> iPhone 5S 64GB"

However, this only happens if I follow the direct path outlined above. My problem is that when I crawl these sites via Scrapy, the breadcrumb doesn't show up - even though with the crawler I am following the path as above (i.e. I start on the Electronics site and then keep going deeper until I reach the product site). I even tinkered with the referrer settings, but nothing helped.

Is there another way, a way I could make these breadcrumb-menus appear?

Would really appreciate some input. :)

Comment: Are you ignoring cookies?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the site implements the breadcrumbs as cookies you are ignoring. You need to pass the session cookies from one request to the subsequent ones. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981440/scrapy-how-to-manage-cookies-sessions) demonstrates cookie usage with scrapy.