# How to get cookie from scrapy response and set the cookie to the next request?

Tags: python, redirect, cookies, scrapy

I have disabled the Default Scrapy cookie option, so that i have to set it manually.

```
COOKIES_ENABLED = False
COOKIES_DEBUG = True
```

Now, i need to set cookie with the value which is received as the response of the same site. I can able to get the cookie as below,

```
cookie = response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')[0].split(";")[0].split("=")
```

now i am trying to set it to the form request by

```
FormRequest.from_response(response,
                formdata={"username": "asldkfs", "pass": "slskd"},
                cookies={cookie[0]:cookie[1]},
                meta = {'dont_redirect': True,'handle_httpstatus_list': [302]},
                callback=self.redirection)

def redirection(self,response): 
    self.log("redirection")
    self.log(response.headers)               
    self.log("Cookie2")
    cook1 = response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')[0].split(";")[0].split("=")
    self.log(cook1)        
    self.log("end cookie2")
    return Request("http://something.net/some/sa/"+response.headers.getlist('Location')[0],cookies={cook1[0]:cook1[1]},
        callback=self.check_login_response)

.
.
.
```

So I could not set the cookie.Do i need to set any other value also or what could be the problem?

Answer (score 15):

The cookies argument only works if you have COOKIES_ENABLED set to True, since CookiesMiddleware handles it.

Hence you have to set it manually on the headers:

```
cookie = response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')[0].split(';')[0]

FormRequest.from_response(response,
            formdata={"username": "asldkfs", "pass": "slskd"},
            headers={'Cookie': cookie}, # <---
            meta = {'dont_redirect': True,'handle_httpstatus_list': [302]},
            callback=self.redirection)
```

Comment: hey I got error `cookie = response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')[0].split(';')[0]
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`\

Answer (score 7):

The [answer from Paulo Romeira](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45367467/2359227) is correct, only the parsing from byte to string is missing:

```
cookie = response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')[0].decode("utf-8").split(";")[0].split("=")
```

Comment: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'`

Answer (score 1):

I think you could not work with cookies if you disabled it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the concepts of creating cookiejars and handling the cookies there (for maintaining sessions in scrapy) using the following strategies documented here in the official scrapy docs:
https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#std:reqmeta-cookiejar

Also refer this stackoverflow issue:
[Scrapy - how to manage cookies/sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981440/scrapy-how-to-manage-cookies-sessions)

Answer (score 1):

If you want a different way other than `response.headers.getlist('Set-Cookie')`, you can do something like:

```py
from scrapy.http.cookies import CookieJar


def response_cookies(response):
    """
    Get cookies from response
    
    @param response scrapy response object
    @return: dict
    """

    obj = CookieJar(policy=None)
    jar = obj.make_cookies(response, response.request)
    cookies = {}
    for cookie in jar:
        cookies[cookie.name] = cookie.value
    return cookies
```