# Load session cookies with scrapy

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to scrape sites that require login, but I'm no sure exactly which are the fields requires to save and load in order to keep the session.

With selenium I'm doing the following to save the cookies:

```
import pickle
import selenium.webdriver 

driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
```

And this to load them:

import pickle
import selenium.webdriver

```
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.google.com")
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)
```

And it works just fine, is it possible to do exactly this using scrapy

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25516223/3923463

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scrapy - how to manage cookies/sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981440/scrapy-how-to-manage-cookies-sessions)

Answer (score 1):

**Sent a request using cookies:**

```py
request_with_cookies = Request(url="http://www.example.com", cookies={'currency': 'USD', 'country': 'UY'})
```

**Get cookies from response:**

```py
cookies_from_response = response.headers[b'Cookies'].decode()
```