# Pass cookies/session across all scrapy navigation

Tags: python, session, cookies, scrapy, scrapy-splash

I'm using scrapy to get some video links in a website. The matter is when I reach some point I can't only get those links if I pass the previous cookies on further links.

How can I tell scrapy to pass them? I'm using splash along with scrapy as I can't get the correct output by just using scrapy.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Scrapy - how to manage cookies/sessions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981440/scrapy-how-to-manage-cookies-sessions)