# Can't scrap a website that checks for security with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I want to scrape: https://9anime.gs/filter?keyword=oshi+n+oko
So I went into my browser and tried to look into its code but I realized that it shows this page,

[Security Checking](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wFUa.png)
And after a little time, it shows
[Redirecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pBJ7Z.png)
For a very little time the url changes and returns back to normal.
[Redirecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NXt8Z.png)
Then the website loads..
[Website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fJTv.png)

I get this response whenever I send a request to the site:
[Codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AJsS.png)
*Inline code didn't work*

I don't really understand what the script does.

Please give me a solution or give me a guideline that I can follow to scrape this site

I tried fake user-agents but it didn't work.
I also tried a little with cookies but I couldn't find which cookies I need to send.

Comment: They are trying to prevent you from violating their copyrighted material.  Scrapy can handle cookies:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4981440/scrapy-how-to-manage-cookies-sessions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Roberts has mentioned as well, the website has a captcha to protect itself against unwanted access. Though, it is possible to access the website through selenium, using browser automation.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
url = 'https://9anime.se/filter?keyword=oshi+n+oko'

driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(ec.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'section[class="block_area block_area-anime none-bg"]'))) # element for search results
```

I am able to access the website and locate the search results section with this code.

Note: I used the *.se* domain, as *.gs* had stopped working for me, but all of the 9anime domains have the same structure.

Comment: Thank you for your kind attention to my problem. I am really glad that you took the time to solve my problem. It works like a charm. Now thanks to you I will be able to do what I want.